# How to Use third party API in hadoop to read files from hdfs if those API uses only local file system path?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have large mbox files and I am using third party API like mstor to parse messages from mbox file using hadoop. I have uploaded those files in hdfs. But the problem is that this API uses only local file system path , similar to shown below

```
MessageStoreApi store = new MessageStoreApi(“file location in locl file system”);
```

I could not find a constructor in this API that would initialize from stream . So I cannot read hdfs stream and initialize it.

Now my question is, should I copy my files from hdfs to  local file system and initialize it from local temporary folder? As thats what I have been doing for now:

Currently My Map function receives path of the mbox files.

```
Map(key=path_of_mbox_file in_hdfs, value=null){

String local_temp_file = CopyToLocalFile(path in hdfs);
MessageStoreApi store = new MessageStoreApi(“local_temp_file”);
//process file

}
```

Or Is there some other solution? I am expecting some solution like what If I increase the block-size so that single file fits in one block and somehow if I can get the location of those blocks in my map function, as mostly map functions will execute on the same node where those blocks are stored then I may not have to always download to local file system? But I am not sure if that will always work :)

Suggestions , comments are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For local filesystem path-like access, HDFS offers two options: HDFS NFS (via NFSv3 mounts) and FUSE-mounted HDFS.

The former is documented under the [Apache Hadoop docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsNfsGateway.html) (CDH users may [follow this instead](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/admin_hdfs_nfsgateway.html))

The latter is documented at the [Apache Hadoop wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/MountableHDFS) (CDH users may find relevant docs [here instead](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_ig_hdfs_mountable.html))

The NFS feature is more maintained upstream than the FUSE option, currently.